# Zend: Autoload both Doctrine_Table and Doctrine_Record

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine, autoload

I've been working with Doctrine_Record classes that autoload just fine for a while; but after some reading, I've decided I would like to implement both Doctrine_Records as well as Custom Table Classes.

So I added this to my bootstrap

```
    $manager->setAttribute(
        Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES,
        true
    );
```

Which has made the Custom table classes work just fine... but it breaks autoloading Records!

How to make both autoload?

I.E. new User.php gets my User Doctrine_Record class and Doctrine_Core::getTable('User') gets my Custom UserTable class.

Here's how it looked (working) before I tried implementing Custom Tables:

```
public function _initDoctrine() {
        require_once 'Doctrine.php';
        /*
         * Autoload Doctrine Library and connect
         * use appconfig.ini doctrine.dsn
         */
        $this   ->getApplication()
                ->getAutoloader()
                ->pushAutoloader(array(
                                'Doctrine',
                                'autoload'),
                                'Doctrine');
        $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
        $manager->setAttribute(
            Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, 
            true
        );

        $manager->setAttribute(
            Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING,
            Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE
        );
            // try these custom tables out!
        // $manager->setAttribute( Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true );

        $config = $this->getOption('doctrine');
        $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($config['dsn'], 'doctrine');
        return $conn;
        // can call flush on the connection to save any unsaved records
    }
```

Thanks

---

**edit:**

Let me clarify.

Not just custom classes.. I already use custom classes which extend Doctrine_Record.

```
class Model_User extends Doctrine_Record {}

$foo = new Model_User;
```

Much of my application currently works around this and will not be changing in that respect.

However, I would like to **ALSO** use [Custom Tables](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/component-overview.html#custom-table-classes)

```
class UserTable extends Doctrine_Table {}

$bar = Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');
```

But, as soon as I enable this (custom table classes) feature to call classes of Doctrine_Table utilising the Table suffix.  Any Doctrine_Record classes I've previously extended and called directly, stops working!  I want to make use of both!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

You must make sure **every** x.php Doctrine_Record class has an associated xTable.php Doctrine_Table class or the record loading will break!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your problem about your custom classes but in any case here is my bootstrap for Doctrine 1.2.4 in ZF, using mysql and UTF-8. It doesn't need a require() and load all my models flawlessly.

```
protected function _initDoctrine()
{
    $this->getApplication()->getAutoloader()
                           ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
    spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));

    $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
    $manager->setAttribute  (
                                Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING,
                                Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE
                            );
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);

    $dsn = $this->getOption('dsn');
    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($dsn, 'doctrine');
    $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_NATIVE_ENUM, true);
    $conn->setCollate('utf8_unicode_ci');
    $conn->setCharset('utf8');
    $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_FREE_QUERY_OBJECTS, true );

    Doctrine::loadModels(APPLICATION_PATH . '/models');
    return $manager;
}
```

Doctrine models are stored in "application/models"

Then in my application/configs/application.ini :

```
autoloadernamespaces[] = "Doctrine"
dsn = "mysql://your_login:your_pass@server_ip/database"
```

Comment: See my edit, I'm trying to achieve both custom classes and custom tables.My custom classes already work fine.